# Does Damage Reduction Stack In Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stacking, damage-reduction

I have not been able to find it stated explicitly anywhere but does damage reduction from different sources stack?

For example I have a [Lycanthropic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lycanthrope) character who has dr10/silver and I was looking at the spell Stoneskin which grants DR10/adamantine. Would these stack or would you simply use the highest one? (So if he was struck with silver you would use the adamantine or if hit with adamantine you would use silver.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

DR doesn't "stack" per [the DR rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Damage-Reduction):

> If a creature has damage reduction from more than one source, the two forms of damage reduction do not stack. Instead, the creature gets the benefit of the best damage reduction in a given situation.

So DR5/magic and DR2/magic don't turn into DR7/magic, but DR10/silver and DR10/adamantine are usable together in that you can pick the one that's best for you at the time.  It's like having resistance to energy (fire) and resistance to energy (cold), you can use both, they aren't subject to stacking because they aren't identical effects.

(Exception: if using the [armor as DR](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/armor-as-damage-reduction) alternate rule, that DR stacks with other DR.)

Comment: Just to note: Having `DR 10/silver` and `DR 10/adamantine` is *effectively* the same as having `DR 10/silver and adamantine` and can be noted as such for succinctness.  This doesn't really help if they're differing amounts (such as `DR 10/silver` and `DR 5/-`).