# DR stacking for alternate rules where armor brings DR

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Ultimate combat introduced alternate rules where armor generates DR/Armor.

With the normal rules DR does not stack ([Does Damage Reduction Stack In Pathfinder?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/40745/does-damage-reduction-stack-in-pathfinder)).

With the alternate rules though there are some exceptions in regards to natural armour stacking there (example in the text is barkskin spell on someone wearing a chainmail).   Now though some abilities grant a DR (like a barbarians). Are these worthless if these alternate rules are used, or do they stack with the DR/armour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Armor as Damage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/armor-as-damage-reduction#TOC-Armor-As-Damage-Reduction1) says:

> Armor in this system keeps all of its normal statistics and qualities, but its armor bonus (including any enhancement bonus added to armor bonus and natural armor bonus ) is converted to DR/armor. The DR an armor provides is equal to its total armor bonus...

... plus some about how it scales with hit dice.

Further,

> DR/Armor: This type of DR blocks the damage of all attacks that would normally be affected by DR, based on the composition of the armor (see [Table: Armor Composition and DR](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/armor-as-damage-reduction#TOC-Table:-Armor-Composition-and-DR)). Unlike most forms of damage reduction, DR/armor stacks with other types of DR. **For instances, when fighting a skeleton with DR 5/bludgeoning and DR 4/armor (+2 for armor, +2 for natural armor ), the skeleton’s DR/armor reduces 9 points of damage from non-bludgeoning attacks, and 4 damage from bludgeoning weapon attacks. Magic weapons and attacks from Large or larger creatures bypass the DR 4/armor, but not the DR 5/bludgeoning.**
>   *(emphasis mine)*

From that table, nonmagical armor grants DR/magic. So, nonmagical armor that would normally grant a +5 Armor bonus to AC instead grants DR 5/armor(magic).

A creature with DR 10/magic and a +2 natural armor bonus instead gains DR 2/armor(adamantine).

That creature ("Bob") wearing that armor would now have:

- DR 5/armor(magic)
- DR 2/armor(adamaintine)
- DR 10/magic

... and gets to apply them *in order*.

Bob gets attacked several times, by differing weapons (all wielded by a normal human with a terrific str bonus). In all cases, the attacker hits and rolls 20 damage.

- a nonmagical, no-special-materials sword: all DR sources apply, Bob takes 3 damage
- a magical, no-special-materials sword: only DR 2/armor(adamantine) applies; Bob takes 18 damage
- a nonmagical adamantine sword: both DR 5/armor(magic) and DR 10/magic apply sequentially, so Bob takes 5 damage
- a magical adamantine sword: all DR sources are bypassed, Bob takes 20 damage

Bob then takes a few levels of Barbarian and gets [DR](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/#TOC-Damage-Reduction-Ex-) 1/- from that class.

Bob now has:

- DR 5/armor(magic)
- DR 2/armor(adamaintine)
- DR 10/magic
- DR 1/-

Now, the normal DR overlapping rules kick in for the DR 10/magic and DR 1/- (ie., magic swords bypass the former so the latter applies, nonmagical swords don't bypass the former (which is better for Bob), so the latter doesn't apply). But, the DR/armor still stacks. Against that same human's attack:

- a nonmagical, no-special-materials sword: all DR sources apply, DR 10/magic trumps DR 1/-, Bob takes 3 damage
- a magical, no-special-materials sword: only DR 2/armor(adamantine) and DR 1/- apply; Bob takes 17 damage
- a nonmagical adamantine sword: both DR 5/armor(magic) and DR 10/magic apply sequentially, with DR 10/magic again trumping DR 1/-, so Bob takes 5 damage
- a magical adamantine sword: all DR sources are bypassed except DR 1/-, Bob takes 19 damage

In short: gaining DR in addition to DR/armor is still useful, subject to the same caveats about DR overlapping that have always been in place. DR/armor is "simply" a second level of DR that applies before those other sources. Actually, gaining DR other ways is probably more important when using DR/armor, since you're likely to be getting hit a lot more than without that optional rule.

Comment: tnx overread that little part 5 times in a row!