# How do I improve survivability of a Barbarian who's limited to light armor only?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, house-rules, barbarian

I'm currently using a Barbarian Half-Orc in a custom made campaign.
The campaign itself is set to hardcore, that means that encouters, enemies and the story itself is really, really hard and fights are deadly if not handled with care.

That said, my DM decided that the Barbarian is a [glass cannon](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85206/is-glass-cannon-a-generally-recognized-phrase) (and that's kinda true), therefore he decided that it can only wear light armor.

I can still spend one talent to have the medium armor training but, as the DM told me, whenever I wear an armor that is not light, I cannot enter rage. 
That means that medium armor is not a viable option.

While I'm absolutely against this house rule (a really bad one, in my opinion) I have to find a way to make the character able to survive.

Currently the character's AC is 17. At level 7.
It's bad. Every enemy NPC that I fight can hit with rolls of 2 or 3 with the base dice.

Here's the character:

> ### Invulnerable Rager level 7
>
> A little bit of DR/- is nice to boost survivability.
>   He uses a Falchion with 2 hands so shield is not viable.
>
> - Stats:
>
>   - Str 20 → +4 when raging / Belt +2 Str
>   - Dex 13
>   - Con 16 → +6 when raging (raging vitality)
>   - Int 11
>   - Wis 14 → Belt +2 Wis
>   - Cha 9
> - Armor is a +1 Chain shirt
>
>   Additional armor is given by a Ring of Protection+1
>
>   Total armor given by equipment is 6.
>
>   Total AC, as said before, is 17.
>
>   Additionally, when raging the barbarian loses 2 AC, but it gains back 2 AC from Beast Totem.
> - Total HP is 79 -> 100 while raging

What I'm asking is: **What can I do/buy/train to considerably improve the survivability of the character?**

For survivability I don't mean only AC, but the whole capacity of the Barbarian to stay alive.

I have little to no gp, but a solution could be a long-term plan that needs amounts of gold that I don't have right now.

**EDIT:** To answer @Thomas Jacobs comment

I actually played this character for a considerable number of session but have been engaged in a fight only 2 times, one of them packing a strong punch but risking the life of the barbarian ( -9 hp, for instance ).
He needs lots and lots of spells from the cleric if the fight is hard enough ( like groups of enemies or bosses )

**Edit 2:** To answer @Joel Harmon comment.

It's not wrong. Trash npcs like local militia do little to no harm, but when it comes to trained mercenaries or bandit leaders (usually levelled fighters/rangers) their attack bonus ranges from +10 to +15. 
When it comes to particular monsters the bonus can range from +15 to +20.
Since it's an open world campaign, the party can go to higher level zones (without being aware of it, ofc) so we can find higher level monsters so the attack bonus can be even higher, but that's a really rare scenario and it's caused by bad party decisions.

Comment: How many sessions have you played with this character? How many times have you come close to dying? How much healing does your character need to not die? This is important information to formulate a question.

Comment: Wait a second. "Currently the character's AC is 17. At level 7. It's bad. Every enemy NPC that I fight can hit with rolls of 2 or 3 with the base dice." At level 7, every opponent has an attack bonus of 14 or 15?! Have you verified that you're calculating this properly?

Comment: He isn't wrong, though. At CR 9 (APL+2, pretty standard for "tough fights") nearly all combatant monsters (read, good BAB) have at least +14, some going even higher due to higher than average str (dragons). It all depends on *what* he is fighting, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The too long, didn’t read here is simple: defense is not something the barbarian is ever going to do well. Trying will only hurt your offense, without appreciably improving your defense. Your survivability comes from killing things dead. Basic armor (maybe *mistmail*), a *cloak of resistance*, and invulnerable rager abilities are quite sufficient here, or at least the best you’re going to reasonably get. When you can, *nightmare boots*, a *cloak of displacement*, and things that grant you *death ward*, *freedom of movement*, and/or *mind blank* are worthwhile, but ultimately, don’t sweat it. Your spellcaster allies are really the ones responsible for neutralizing threats before you can kill them. Your job is to kill them.

To understand why this is *the* answer, and any attempt to bolster your defenses is only going to hurt you, there are a few facts of Pathfinder that you need to understand first:

## Pathfinder is not a balanced game

Not every class is equally capable. Not every class is equally flexible. Some classes are very limited in what they can and cannot do. Some classes cannot do much of *anything* outside their specialty. Some of those classes *aren’t even that good at that specialty*. This is an unfortunate reality, but it *is* reality and you have to understand it.

People who analyze Pathfinder and its imbalances organize classes into tiers, from 1, classes that can do everything, to 5, classes that can only do one thing and even that not particularly well, or struggle doing a mish-mash of things. See [What tier are the Pathfinder classes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114425/4563) for more details.

## Barbarian is not a flexible class

Barbarians deal damage. That is what they do. They aren’t necessarily the best in the game at it, but they’re pretty good at it.

They are not good at *anything* else. They cannot be made to be. Attempting to do so will only throw away lots of damage potential for extremely limited skills in other fields.

That puts barbarian in tier 4. They’re pretty good at damage-dealing, and that’s a pretty important thing to be good at, so they’re better than several classes, but it still puts barbarians on the lower end here.

## The best defense is a strong offense, anyway

Other classes can try to get some defenses. High-Dex can give you decent AC, magic can give you other non-AC defenses, and so on. Barbarians don’t have those options, particularly high-Strength barbarians like you (a barbarian *might* be able to try doing a high-Dex finesse barbarian approach, maybe, but that isn’t your character).

But ultimately, that only matters so much. Pathfinder is a *very* glass-cannon-y game. At low-mid levels (above 1st or 2nd or so, but below 10th to say the least), there can be some back and forth, but at high levels (and the very earliest levels), it really is [rocket tag](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RocketTagGameplay) (warning: TVTropes link). Consider [this analysis of what it takes to maintain relevant AC](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fqPgj0pBGpgxPXI9lUEsipZiBKYaONFx1W-A-IO8rI0/edit#gid=0). A high-Dex character needs to spend nearly 20% of his or her wealth to maintain AC at 20th level (and to maintain it at all levels can take as much as 95%!). For a heavy-armor, low-Dex character, that number is 35% at 17th, *and it isn’t even possible beyond that point*.

And that’s only AC: AC is the worst defense in the game. Too many things ignore it, and most of the time it only protects you from hp damage (which only matters once you run out, while a failed saving throw often means you lose immediately). So optimal characters will fall behind in AC regardless, because it costs too much to do otherwise.

So you’re right, this is a bad houserule. There is nothing about the barbarian class that justifies nerfing it. But ultimately, it *doesn’t really matter.* All it really means is that you’ll start falling behind, and ignoring, your AC slightly earlier than you might otherwise—maybe. Personally, I *prefer* light armor most of the time, because the cost, weight, and armor check penalty of medium or heavy armor isn’t worth it to me. I would also very likely **sell** that *ring of protection*, because it’s worth a whole lot in gold pieces, while its deflection bonus to AC isn’t worth a whole lot to me (though, deflection is much better than armor or natural armor or shield).

So your best hope for survivability is to play to your strengths, and kill things dead before they get a chance to pose a threat. Throwing away lots and lots of damage potential only leaves threats more opportunities to hurt you, and you cannot trade that damage potential away for similarly-strong defenses. Those defenses simply *do not exist* for you to take. At very-low levels, you need to pick up the basics, and at very-high levels there are some potent options, but in between, really, just focus on killing things.

#### On having a strong offense

Use a two-handed weapon. Have, and use, Power Attack and Furious Focus. A [*furious*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/furious/) weapon isn’t a terrible choice. Choose the Beast Totem, and get [pounce](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/beast-totem-greater-su/) at 10th level. Consider getting a mount, a lance, and Spirited Charge. Or even worship Gorum, or your setting’s equivalent, and taking his [Greatsword Battler divine fighting technique](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/divine-fighting-technique-combat/#TOC-Greatsword-Battler-)—then you can take the Vital Strike line and put it to solid use (probably better than any other class).

But the goal here is simple: you charge things, and kill them. Dead and destroyed things can’t hurt you.

If you want a little more flexibility, barbarians are also pretty good at the Intimidate game; still offense, but gives you a little more ability to deal with things you can’t kill outright. [Cornugon Smash](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cornugon-smash-combat/) is pretty solid. [Intimidating Prowess](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/intimidating-prowess-combat-final/), however, is an obnoxious feat tax, but you’d probably need it to go this route.

#### Leave protecting people to the spellcasters

That’s what they’re there for. They should be dividing foes with walls, blinding foes with darkness or clouds or just straight blinding them, hampering foes’ actions, and so on and so forth. In the face of competent spellcasting, your enemies should not be able to mount a significant offense in the first place. Battlefield control, debuffing enemies, and buffing allies are some of the best uses of magic.

Dealing damage, that is, blasting, is a really poor use of magic. They should let you deal the damage, you’re made for it and there are so many more important things they need to be doing.

#### Personal defenses you *should* have

There are certain, basic, entry-level defenses that every character should always have, even if the spellcasters are protecting people with debuffs and battlefield control. They’re just really cheap and easy to get, so there’s no reason not to.

1. Mundane armor that is the best in its weight class and that you have proficiency with from your class—for you, a chain shirt or leather lamellar. Mundane armor is cheap and even if armored AC is low-value, it tends to give you a big wodge of it for effectively nothing.

   - **If** not using a weapon: a buckler, light shield, or heavy shield. Darkwood or mithral if necessary to avoid armor check penalty, arcane spell failure, and/or nonproficiency penalties (if ACP is 0, nonproficiency with a shield has no drawback). Since you are a barbarian, you are weapon-based, and should not use a shield anyway. But for people who don’t care about weapons, this is an almost-free boost to AC, and another platform for magical properties.
2. A +1 enhancement bonus to your armor. Mandatory for any other magic.

   - A +1 enhancement bonus to your shield, if any. Mandatory for any other magic, which is really the whole reason to bother with a shield in the first place.
3. The highest-bonus *cloak of resistance* you can afford. *Cloaks of resistance* apply to all saves, so unlike armor they apply to a huge array of particularly-dangerous effects, and they are reasonably priced. Always get the best you can.

Beyond that, other options are mostly terrible, but there are a few things worth mentioning, **especially** if you can get them for mere gold instead of having to spend feats and class features on them.

- <s>Using a shield alongside a weapon.</s> Cuts way too hard into your offense; not worth it.
- <s>Higher enhancement bonuses to armor or shields.</s> Don’t buy these; they are overpriced. Special armor properties (discussed in more detail below) are the real benefit of magic armor.
- <s>Better armor due to Armor Proficiency feats.</s> **No!** Feats are precious, precious things. A +2 bump to armored AC, particularly when tacked on to larger armor check penalties and slower speeds, isn’t worth very much at all.
- <s>An *amulet of natural armor* of any kind.</s> These cost the same as enhancement bonuses to armor, and cannot have special armor properties. Pass for the same reasons you pass on higher enhancement bonuses to armor.
- <s>A *ring of protection* of any kind.</s> More debatable, but ultimately these are **really** expensive for a relatively-small boost. Deflection bonuses are good, but the amount of gold they’re worth is better-spent elsewhere. Maybe a *ring of protection +1* is OK enough; since the cost scales quadratically the +1 version isn’t too bad, and ya know, you already have one.
- <s>Toughness.</s> Toughness is a mediocre feat for a low-hp class like wizard. For a high-hp class like barbarian, it’s a complete waste of time. Your big HD, high Constitution, and bonuses from rage should cover your hp well. There are more important things to use feats on.
- <s>Healing of your own.</s> You’re a barbarian, you can’t heal people, not even yourself. Renewed Vigor and Regenerative Vigor are terrible rage powers; spending a standard action in combat is an enormous cost (you are probably only going to get 2-3 of those in a given fight), and it’s a tiny amount of healing. Let the spellcasters heal you (and help them buy *wands of cure light wounds*).
- **Damage Reduction from invulnerable rager.** This is pretty solid; the number isn’t terribly large but it’s **much** bigger than you usually see, and the cost isn’t very high (uncanny dodge is pretty good, but improved uncanny dodge is pretty niche and the regular barbarian DR is minuscule, and trap sense is garbage). You are already ahead of the game by having this.
- <s>Damage Reduction from items, feats, or other class features.</s> Damage reduction almost-always has one of the following flaws:

  - it comes in very small amounts (like the regular barbarian DR),
  - it is exceedingly conditional or limited (like Bolstering Resilience’s bonus against a *single attack*, that then leaves you fatigued, or Stalwart needing you to nuke your offense using Total Defense or Combat Expertise), or
  - is bypassed by magic (which means it’s ignored by every real threat anyway).

  It also costs massively to get those small amounts—feats, rage powers, these are precious, precious things. They aren’t worth the cost. (This is *especially* true for an invulnerable rager, since most things won’t stack with the DR you already have. But really, even if you weren’t an invulnverable rager, you still shouldn’t get these.)
- **Miss chances.** These are very good defenses, because they work equally-well against all opponents. Against particularly-dangerous opponents, that’s an advantage because it ignores their skills (and against not-particularly-dangerous opponents, we don’t care). A [*mistmail*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/mistmail/) is a fine armor, for example: 3 minutes’ worth of 20% miss chance is a great deal at 2,250 gp. Paying for improved versions that have more uses per day, or simply buying more *mistmails* and changing between combats, is a really good choice as you level—or would be, if it weren’t for the excellent [*nightmare boots*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-nightmare/) that you could buy instead. At higher levels, a [*cloak of displacement*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-of-displacement/) is fantastic. You can also ask your GM about possibly commissioning custom items of *blur* and/or *mirror image* for more miss chances; these arguably stack since they are for different reasons.
- **Immunities.** The endgame, these are the real goal—effects you don’t have to worry about at all are effects that you’ll be happy to have enemies waste time trying. *Death ward*, *freedom of movement*, and *mind blank* are the best examples, and the latter two come in (very expensive) ring form. *Death ward* could be accessible from a (also likely expensive) custom magic item; speak with your GM once you get high enough in level to be considering these expenses. *Fortification* armor properties also fall in this category.
- **Special armor properties.** In addition to the aforementioned *fortification*, armor properties are a relatively-cheap way to get defenses. Since AC ends up being too difficult to bother with, most armor properties are worth more than their equivalent enhancement cost to you. They can also offer other, more unusual features, like *delving*’s 10-ft. burrow speed, a rather interesting option that could allow you to bypass ambushes and get the drop on opponents by coming from unexpected angles. I recommend avoiding *spell resistance*, though; the numbers aren’t great and you’re just as likely to resist your ally’s buff or healing spell as you are to avoid the enemy’s attacks. Note that some of these, like *stanching*, may make enhancement bonuses to your armor more valuable than they’d otherwise be, but that also plays against them because they effectively cost more than they appear as you need to get otherwise-useless enhancement bonuses.

  - *+1 animated darkwood heavy shield* with other properties. At the very high-end, it may be cheaper to add new special properties to a *+1 animated darkwood heavy shield* than to add the same property to your armor. A darkwood heavy shield has no armor check penalty (so you take no penalties for using it without proficiency), and since it’s *animated* it doesn’t interfere with your offense. Also offers a +3 shield bonus to AC, but you *really* shouldn’t care by the time this becomes a sensible option. You may very likely never reach the point where you actually want one of these.

Answer (score 15):

### Your problem isn't Light Armor

The difference between the best mundane light armor (chain shirt, +4 AC) and the best mundane medium armor (chainmail/lamellar, +6) is only two points more on your already low AC. Here are a few problems I see:

- No shield, this would increase your AC by 2 points or more depending on magical enhancements;
- Rage lowers your AC, and there is nothing you can do about this (unless you [Retrain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining/));
- Your archetype favors getting hit. Reducing damage is the main ability you gain from it;
- Your dexterity is low.

That said, that issue is not unheard of, all barbarians face that problem, either because Rage lowers the AC of all barbarians, with the exceptions of a few already incompatible archetypes (like [dreadnought](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo-barbarian-archetypes/dreadnought-barbarian-archetype/) or [savage technologist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/archetypes/paizo-barbarian-archetypes/savage-technologist)), or because wielding weapons two-handed is far superior (high strength and [power attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat-final/) bonuses).

However, **I do not recommend that you focus on increasing your AC**. AC is generally a stat that is very costly to increase, and the return may not be that useful to your character because there are many other ways for him to get hurt (touch attacks, spells, area effects, etc). Instead, I would recommend you look at these options:

- [Bolstered Resilience](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/bolstered-resilience/) feat. This allows you to double your DR for a single attack at the cost of getting *Fatigued* on the next round;
- Get additional hit points (with [Toughness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/toughness-final/) for example);
- Rage powers to increase your survivability, like [Renewed Vigor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/renewed-vigor-ex) and [Regenerative Vigor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/regenerative-vigor-ex);
- [Armor Material Expertise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/armor-material-expertise-armor-mastery/), twice per day you can convert half of a lethal damage done to nonlethal, which counts double your DR from your archetype.
- [Cord of Stubborn Resolve](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cord-of-stubborn-resolve/) (15,000 gp) to avoid getting fatigued after a rage, which has a nice synergy with other abilities (like *Bolstered Resilience*);
- [Stalwart](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/stalwart/) and [Improved Stalwart](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-stalwart/) explicitly allows stacking with your barbarian's DR. This allows you to *Fight Defensively* and add up to +3 to your DR/- at the cost of -4 to attack rolls. Or +4 to DR/- at the cost of -2 to attacks using [Crane Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crane-style-combat-style/). But the requirements for this are heavy.
- Finally, obtain ways to get concealment, like [Mistmail](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/mistmail/) (2,250 gp), [Nightmare Boots](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-nightmare/) (8,500 gp), [Amulet of Spirits (Waves)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-the-spirits/) (10,000 gp) or [Cloak of Displacement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-of-displacement/) (24,000 gp).

Note that the [Increased Damage Reduction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/increased-damage-reduction-ex) rage power doesn't increase your invulnerable rager's DR, only the damage reduction class ability from the base barbarian, as per [this FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9uqg).

Also, [Concealment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Concealment) is the only defensive ability that will remain balanced throughout all levels, you may face an enemy that ignores concealment, but the majority of creatures don't, so even a 20% miss chance will save you from getting hit 20% of the time, regardless of level.

But if you insist on getting more AC, here are a few options that you can plan to take for the next few levels:

- [Amulet of Natural Armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-natural-armor/) (2,000+ gp);
- [Dusty Rose Prism](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/dusty-rose-prism-ioun-stone/) (5,000 gp), +1 insight to AC;
- [Sanguine Talisman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/talisman-sanguine/) (13,500+ gp), +1 profane to AC and cool flavor;
- Increase your [dexterity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-incredible-dexterity/), lighter armors favor higher dexterity characters (see also the [Belt of Physical Perfection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-physical-perfection/));
- [Guarded Stance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/guarded-stance-ex) rage power. This grants a +1 (+1/6 levels) dodge bonus for *con mod* rounds at the cost of a move action;
- Grab a shield. Even a +1 buckler (1,000 gp) will grant you +2 AC at the cost of -1 on attacks. Larger shields can be used with the [Animated](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/animated/) enchantment;
- [Dodge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dodge-combat-final/). Though this is a high cost (a feat) for a single +1 dodge to AC.
- [Crane Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crane-style-combat-style/), as mentioned earlier, will allow you to take -2 to attacks to increase your AC by 4 points (or +3 without 5 ranks in acrobatics), and is viable if you already took Dodge;
- [Shield of Swings](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/shield-of-swings-combat/), +4 shield to AC at cost of reducing damage by half. This is not recommended as the point of using a weapon two-handed is to increase it's damage;
- [Mithral](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Mithral) and [Medium Armor Proficiency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/armor-proficiency-medium/) with a chainmail. This is also a bad deal, you will gain (at best) +2 to AC, and you won't really benefit from the mithral material, which raises your Dex cap on the armor.

In my personal experience, most barbarians are about 5-6 points behind fighters in armor class, even before they rage. But fighters that decide to not wear shields also have a similar AC.

Temporary or on-use solutions are good too. You described that sometimes you can handle *moonks* just fine, so wielding a two-hander is actually a very good idea. But when you fight one of those *boss* monsters, you could use a [Potion of Blur](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blur/) or similar magic item, since you dont need to have that option available on every fight.

- [Shoanti Warpaint (Orange)](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Shoanti%20war%20paintBlack) (900 gp), this grants an additional DR 1/- that stacks with your barbarian ability and lasts 24 hours;
- Taking a [Deific Obedience](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/deific-obedience/) (12th level) to follow either [Sivanah](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/DeityDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Sivanah) or [Desna](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/DeityDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Desna) (which has a better overall *Obedience*) will allow you to cast blur 2/day;

### A dead enemy can't hit you back

Instead of focusing on your defense, you can focus on your offense. Killing enemies quicker will prevent them from having a chance from attacking you, and this also means that you won't have to do anything different from what you are already doing.

So instead of investing money on magic items, or wasting feats trying to survive for one more round, you can increase your damage output even more, by causing more damage (like [Elemental Rage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/elemental-rage-su), or better magic weapons), having a higher chance of critical ([Critical feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/critical-feats/), you have a falchion after all), getting more attacks (like [Animal Fury](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/animal-fury-ex/)), causing negative conditions, etc. So your enemy is dead before they have that *one more round* to attack you.

Abilities that grant negative conditions, such as [shaken](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Shaken), [nauseated](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Nauseated), [exhausted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Exhausted), [blinded](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Blinded), or [sickened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Sickened), are all good options if you decide to go this route, as some of those will lower your enemy strengths and allow all allies to have better chances against them. Many of these conditions will apply penalties to their attack rolls, or AC, or even prevent them from full attacking you or your allies. You said you wield a falchion (critical on 18-20), so take a look at the .

Keep in mind that even if enemies can easily hit you, due to your good BAB and high strength, you can pretty much hit everything the GM puts against you as well.

Comment: The comments attached to this answer have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72783/discussion-on-answer-by-shadowkras-how-do-i-improve-survivability-of-a-barbarian) for cleanup.

Answer (score 5):

### If you can't avoid the hit, endure it.

Based on what you say, the NPCs can hit you with a 2 or 3 on d20, that is a terrible truth for your character, you're basically a sitting duck hoping for a natural 1 to be safe. In that case, be a mighty crazy tough as diamond sitting duck and deal with them before they can deal with you.

**Pathfinder:**

- **Toughness** (Pathfinder RPG Core Rulebook): +3HP and +1HP to every HD after the third.
- **Improved Toughness** (Forgotten Core Feats [3rd party]): +1 HP/level.
- **Constitution Enhancement** (Several books): Go for it, the more, the merrier. Remember, same type bonuses doesn't stack.
- **Raging Vitality** (Advanced Player's Guide): +2 morale Con bonus while raging, even if you fall unconscious the rage keep going.
- **Increased Damage Reduction** (Rage Power Lvl 8): While raging, your DR X/- increase by 1. You can take this rage power up to 3 times.
- **Rage Powers** (Several books): Rage Powers that heal or prevent damage in some way are what you're looking for, things like Greater Daemon Totem, Renewed Vigor or Regenerative Vigor.

In case it is allowed, here is some **Dungeons & Dragons 3.5** stuff:

- **Healing Armor Property** (MIC 12): +8000gp cost, heals you 2d8+5 HP as swift (command) or automatically if you fall between -1 and -9 HP. Works once per day.
- **Amulet of Tears** (MIC 70): 2300gp, 3 charges that grant temporary hp based on charges used.
- **Elixir of Adamantine Blood** (MIC 153): This is more of a last resource, an expendable 500gp elixir that gives you 10 temporary hp, but 20 if you're using an adamantine armor.

This list isn't by any way exclusive, there are lots of other ways for you to improve your character resilience.

Comment: The question is marked Pathfinder; you have several 3.5 sources there.

Comment: About [damage reduction stacking](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/40745/does-damage-reduction-stack-in-pathfinder).

Comment: @KRyan They are so compatible and people mix them so frequently that I did it automatically, like a natural reflex.

Comment: They certainly are usable together (I do), but it’s *not* automatic—conversion is necessary. Even if it’s usually straight-forward, it takes effort and can’t be assumed. Generally, we expect 3.5 material to only be offered in questions tagged 3.5. If you want to suggest incorporating some 3.5 material, you should call that out in a separate section.

Comment: The critiques being made here are implicitly suggesting that you [edit] the answer to improve it, not just wondering why it was written this way. I mention this because that might not be obvious and nobody has said so yet. :) You aren't obliged to edit, but since it may improve the answer, you may decide it's beneficial to you. (One way I might suggest considering, is to sort the PF and D&D material into two lists, to allow the reader to more easily see what's relevant to *their* situation, instead of having to sort the lists themselves. That's not the only edit option, of course.)

Comment: Improved Toughness does not exist in (first-party) Pathfinder material; the Pathfinder +1 hp/level feat is just Toughness (in 3.5e, where Toughness was just +3 hp, there *was* an Improved Toughness feat with that effect).

Comment: @KRyan Indeed, but it does exist as a 3rd party book associated to Pathfinder. I'll add Toughness there and make it clear the other as 3rd party.

Comment: The 3rd-party Improved Toughness feat seems to... just do what Toughness did, again? I guess PF Toughness doesn’t specify you can take it more than once, but on the other hand, it’s a pretty mediocre feat so taking it twice seems... unwise. (But in any event, I’ve removed my downvote, in case that was unclear. Separating PF and 3.5 material helps.)

Comment: The default rule is that you can't take a feat twice, unless the feat allows you to.

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors to resilience and vast numbers of options for each.  In some sort of order, the factors and some example improvements are:

### 1. Don't get targeted

How stealthy are you and the rest of your party?  If you can boost your DEX (see below) and put some points in Stealth (have you?) then wearing only light armour you aren't *that* noisy.  Look for options that get your character in close before the fighting starts, especially invisibility (via potion, friendly spellcaster or ring).

### 2a.  Don't get hit

Now we get to AC.  As others have stated, your build is more conducive to surviving hits than avoiding them.  However, four basic classes of "hardware" options exist:

- Increase your dexterity - consider taking your level 8 attribute    increase as DEX and get an item to increase your DEX by +4 (eg Belt    of Incredible Dexterity, Belt of Physical Perfection).  Once your DEX    is 18 your AC is equal to that of chainmail and only one less than a    breastplate.  If you can get a Mithral chain shirt then you can    benefit from another 2 points of DEX bonus if you can get them.
- Increase your natural armour bonus - most common means is through Amulet of Natural Armour
- Increase your armour bonus - get a higher level chain shirt
- Increase your deflection bonus - get a better ring of protection or similar

All of these options are fairly expensive, and you may be better off spending your gold on the other aspects listed.

I am not going to explore the feats which increase armour class - too broad, and unrelated to the initial light vs medium armour issue.

### 2b.  Still don't get hit

Look for options that give a miss chance - blur, blink, invisibility.  Unless you have a friendly spellcaster willing to buff you with these spells regularly or a massive stockpile of potions, Dust of Disappearance etc, one of the best options is a Ring of Blinking - sustained 50% miss chance.

### 3.  Don't take a crit or sneak attack

The biggest downside to your situation of being hit with base rolls of 2 or 3 is that potential crits against you will almost always become critical hits.  So, rather than spending your hard-looted cash on armour with a higher magical AC bonus, you may be better off spending it on getting the best level of fortification you can.  This is especially important if you are facing enemies with Sneak Attack given that your character has sacrificed Improved Uncanny Dodge by becoming an Invulnerable Rager.

### 4.  Take the hit

One of a barbarian's strengths is that they wear the hits and keep going.  Increase your hitpoints through Toughness and/or CON increases, especially magic items such as Belt of Mighty Constitution / Belt of Physical Perfection.  Increase your damage resistance through Increased Damage Reduction.

### 5.  Don't let them have another hit

The second barbarian strength is dealing out masses of damage to end fights quickly.  This is outside the scope of the question, but when working out how to spend your gold and feats remember that there's no point spending x resources on gaining the ability to survive one more round in combat if spending the same x resources will let you end the combat 2 rounds sooner.

Answer (score 1):

### Ignore AC.

You know that AC is not going to be a strong point, so ignore it. Focus on killing things, and doing it fast, which barbarians are usually good at doing. So what to do?
You can spend so many gold pieces getting items that will only protect you from the third iterative of a bad guy, but by then, he still beat you badly.

### Get concealment.

A *[cloak of displacement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-of-displacement/)* is my #1 recommendation as an alternative to AC. It gives you 15 rounds of 50% displacement. Therefore for 15 rounds, the bad guys will miss every other attack, effectively halving the damage you take.

At 50k, it is a pretty nice chunk of change, but it makes you significantly tougher in combat.

True, there are creatures that ignore that, but that is very nice against most monsters and their **primary** attacks.

Comment: Finally, a good answer to the question.

Comment: @KRyan It would be an awesome answer to the question if it was feasible. He told he is just level 7 with little to no gp, so a 50k gp solution is no solution at all at the moment.

Comment: @AguinaldoSilvestre Honestly, “ignore AC” alone is a better answer than other answers here. AC is a terrible, low-value, high-cost defense, and should just be ignored.

Comment: @KRyan I don't think it was a groundbreaking answer since I ignored AC completely and ShadowKras also avoided it but put it there in case he insisted on it and even suggested the same displacement few hours earlier. Then I can't see it as a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

There are feats to get your HP and AC a little bit higher, also, spending some money on magical items is always a good investment, a DEX or CON boosting item or an item infused with a level 1 shield spell or focusing on getting a higher DR, there are plenty of other ways you can avoid getting damage, in your case is harder, since you're a barbarian, you'll likely be the center of attention for the enemies, but if there's a tank on your party, try to make a strategy with him, where he tanks while you kill.

Comment: The questions is asking for examples; this answer could use some more body.