# Where can I find this feat (chain?) that trades dodge AC bonuses for damage reduction?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, content-identification

Long story short I’m in an insanely high powered campaign where stuff still passes my ac at 22 ac more often than not. So while searching for ways to get my ac higher I found [this post](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2plbh?Unarmored-Fighter#10) online that had an answer which said the following inspiring me to go the dr route. Even if dr only lowers damage it still applies more often than ac in this special case.

> There is a feat chain that allows you to convert dodge bonuses to AC
>   into double the same amount of DR. Stack that on a superstitious
>   barbarian and you might have someone durable enough to operate without
>   armour or magic. A level or two of Lore Warden might help out.

I want to know where to find that feat.

Comment: In a high-powered environment, AC is a losing strategy. Take what you can get for nearly free (best +1 armor of your weight class, +1 shield if not concerned with weapon damage), and ignore the rest and invest resources into other defenses. Which is kind of what you’re doing here with this feat, but DR isn’t much better, and you still have to pay the overpriced costs for the dodge bonuses to AC to convert... See [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114962/4563) for more information. (To be clear, still totally a valid question, +1, just wanted to highlight other useful resources.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the feats being suggested are [Stalwart](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/stalwart) and [Improved Stalwart](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-stalwart). Stalwart has a reasonably high investment to gain (two pre-requisite feats, one of which does very little, and the other only kicking in when you would fall unconscious), and only give about the same benefit as the [Stoneskin](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/stoneskin/) spell.

A [Belt of Stoneskin](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-stoneskin/) would provide comparable benefits once a day, without the feat investment.

(revealed by a quick text search of d20pfsrd)